# How to change Navbar back button color in Reactive Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I am using React Native to develop apps.The thing is that the Back button and arrow in left are always using the default blue color,how to change it to another color?

Comment: [react-native-router-flux ](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md)  have a property "backButtonTextStyle" which can change text color, but it also can't change the color in arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The default back button in react-native-router-flux is an actual image that they are using which explains why you cannot change it. However, they provide you a way to override it. Have a quick look at the [navigation bar docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#navigation-bar).